# What steps does the system go through when handling an SSH connection?

Tags: shell, ssh, pam

What steps does the system go through when handling an SSH connection?

1. We try to log in via ssh
2. `sshd` starts pam and pam module to authenticate us
3. Depending on pam configuration, we need to provide username and password (pam checks `passwd` and `shadow` files)
4. pam checks for `hosts.allow/deny`, `/etc/shells`, and other things
5. If everything goes fine we are logged in
6. ???
7. Shell is started

So my question is what mechanism is responsible for checking which shell is assigned to the user in their `passwd` file (in step 6)? Is it pam itself, some specific pam module, `sshd`, or something else? I know that I can replace the `passwd` file (for checking username and password) by writing a pam module, but how can I replace the `passwd` file for the shell entry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, PAM doesn't determine the user's shell, this is left to the application. PAM's session modules perform generic actions and checks that must be done for on every login using that particular service. If the application then wants to start a shell, it is free to do so, and will typically look up the shell in the user database.

Assuming your question is about [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.org/), that's exactly what it does: once the user is authenticated, and the PAM session stuff has been done (if configured to use PAM¹), the ssh server looks up the shell in the user database (directly, not through the PAM library).

The user database isn't limited to `/usr/passwd` and friends. On Linux (which I assume you're using since you mention `shadow`), what makes up the user database is determined by the `passwd` setting in [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf). In multi-computer setups, common additions to the local database are [NIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service) and [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP). If you want to use a shell that isn't the one in `/etc/passwd`, this may be what to configure (although it would be a bit strange, and maybe people can offer better suggestions if you tell us what you're trying to accomplish).

If you want to have users without full shell access, the natural solution is to change `/etc/passwd` to put a restricted shell — perhaps [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/) to allow only a few file-copying-type applications such as scp, rsync and cvs. You can also use forced commands in the user's [`~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8).

If you'd like to see a trace of what the ssh server is doing, start the daemon as `ssh -ddd`. You can also get the client's view with `ssh -vvv`, though here the server's view is what will interest you most.

¹ 
<sub>OpenSSH only uses PAM if it is configured with PAM support and the `UsePAM` directive is set to `yes` in `sshd_config`. Even when it uses PAM, it offers other authentication methods in addition to PAM; in particular public key authentication does not go through PAM.</sub>

Comment: I want to allow users of my aplication to log in to shell as normal user without creating account in system. Users data (username, pass and shell) will be stored in sqlite db. First step is sqlite pam module that authenticate users agains db. Second step is to provide shell readed from database. So I think It could be accomplished by writing proper nis module. Thans for answer...

Comment: @pbm: I don't think you want `nis`, rather `db` (or perhaps a custom module).

Comment: it's typo.. I meant "by writing proper (custom) nss module"...