# Weird SSH issue, ssh works with -t but freezes without it

Tags: shell, ssh, login

When I `ssh` into one of my servers, it seems to log in, but then hangs before giving me the prompt (`message debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0 is the last log entry`).

Though the odd thing is `ssh -t "/bin/bash"` works when `ssh` doesn't.

*What I have found out so far*

- I can log in fine from servers in the same geographical location normally
- If I `ssh -t '/bin/bash'` - I can log in perfectly from ANY location.
- If I use `rsync` *to* the server , it seems to work, and then locks
- If I use `rsync` *from* the server, it works without problem

*What I have tried*

- removing or changing all login options `.profile`, `.bashrc /etc/profile`
- Changing the `ssh_config` *and/or* `sshd_config` to one from an identical server that works fine
- I've checked the routing
- I've had a network expert examine `tcpdump` to no avail (though there do seem to be a lot of re-transmissions)

*I really can't think of anything else*

Apart from a dodgy network card driver/firmware.

Comment: Are there any `match` statements in `sshd_config`? Is only one instance of `sshd` running?

Comment: no match statements and only one sshd running

Comment: but thats definitely something I didnt think of, so thx

Comment: What happens if you ssh from locally? From a VM hosted on the same physical machine? From the same network segment? If you run another instance of sshd on a different port? Do you have anything unusual in `.ssh/authorized_keys` such as `command=…`? Have you gone through all the firewall rules to see if one might accidentally block some SSH packets?

Comment: Can you Ctrl+C while the SSH connection is hanging and get to a prompt? The prompt won't be your normal prompt. If this is the issue then you likely have a problem in your `/etc/profile.d/*` or `/etc/bashrc` files.

Comment: Does pressing "<Enter>~?" do anything?  That's three keypresses, enter tilde questionmark.

Comment: When you can log in, what is your default shell in /etc/passwd? If you can log in using the bash shell, then it sounds like the default shell is something other than the bash shell.

Comment: What happens with `ssh -T`? capital `T`

Comment: Thanks for all the info, so far I have found: I can ssh from anything in the same datacentre (-t is required from outside the DC). I've tried removing all config and .ssh folder to no avail. -T still fails .... more ....

Comment: .... more... ssh doesn't get a prompt at all. but Enter~? worked (I didn't even know that existed ;)  - From all the logs everything looks like it worked, it just doesn't give me the prompt

Comment: @godlygeek what is that supposed to do?

Answer (score 5):

That may comes from a problem in the profile.
When you connect with `ssh -t /bin/bash`  your shell will not 'login', it will not source the `/etc/profile` nor the `~/.profile` and  `~/.bashrc`...

So after connecting,  put the shell in debug mode then source each file to find what is blocking inside :

```
set -x 
. /etc/profile 
...and so on
```

### EDIT

Note that I was wrong, the .bashrc file will be sourced by any interactive shell (so only the profile, profile.d files matter here).

Try to make the list of the different phases of the connection process. 
Something like this

1) ssh connecting (config,...)
2) login (PAM, tty, wtmp, ...)
3) starting the shell   (profile, home dir access,  ... )

To check the (1) you could start the sshd daemon in debug mode. For that you need to start another sshd, listening to a dedicated port (not on port 22 so no need to stop the regular sshd daemon) .

```
# /usr/sbin/sshd -p 2222 -ddd
```

That sshd will accepts only one connection and will not goes into background. 
Open another terminal and connect to that ssh session.

```
# ssh -vvv -p 2222 user@host
```

You could compare the messages you get with the one of another server of the same brand. 
Then you will know if the problem is on the ssh side or not.

(-ddd and -vvv are the maximum debug level, you can tune that)

I got that [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4055/what-steps-does-the-system-go-through-when-handling-an-ssh-connection),  much more detailed.

Comment: I was sooooo hoping this was the answer, even if it isn't, thankyou for the explanation of the difference, as it will help me solve the issue. I tried moving all profile related stuff, and even using a blank /root folder, but nothing worked (even different log in shells).

Answer (score 3):

**The answer to my problem**
Turns out it was a networking issue. I eventually found out that by dropping the MTU of all the network cards down a bit, the problem went away.

Most likely something is misconfigured for that network, but I can now prove that and hand it over to the network team (who kept telling me it was a server issue).

**Be aware though, this is a last resort** 
The peculiarity I had was that ssh server worked from same subnet but not outside it, and ssh -t '/bin/bash' worked from anywhere.

I also had rsyncs that would start fine, but at some point just hang, or drop the connection.

So if you are looking at this answer, try the others above first, and ONLY if you get oddities like mine, is this likely to help.

So thanks for all the help. I tried everything, and it taught me loads, and let me confirm it had nothing to do with the server (which is everything I had hoped for).

**So thank you to everyone who helped**

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem when I used a nested virtualization platform recently.

It works after reducing MTU from 1500 to 1400 on the source or destination server.

```
/sbin/ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1400
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `ssh some_user@some_host /bin/bash`, what you are doing is launching *some_user*'s shell (as defined in `/etc/passwd` on *some_host*) and then executing the given command, `/bin/bash`, from within that shell.

Now, *some_user*'s shell (let's assume it's also `bash`) isn't being launched interactively (it's executing the given command instead). So it doesn't allocate a pty (a *pseudo-terminal*) and this means there isn't a pty for the issued command to use so it starts non-interactively.

In the example, the requested `/bin/bash` command is launched but it appears to hang.

You can fix this by asking `ssh` to create a pty anyway so that there is one available for the shell and its child processes. This is what `-t` does.

```
    $ ssh -t some_user@some_host bash
```

You can also fix this by forcing the command to create a pty. For `bash`, you do this by passing a `-i` argument. The following command-line should also work:

```
$ ssh some_user@some_host bash -i
```

Note, however that in this latter case, the shell cannot access `/dev/tty` and this results in a warning:

```
bash: no job control in this shell
```

The reasons for this are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11821441). This may or may not be a problem depending on what you plan to do in the shell but using `ssh -t` is probably the better option.

(note that you can just pass `bash` as the command because it should be on the path of the user's default shell anyway)